# Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true'

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, angular-material

I am doing validation for Dropdowns. I have three dropdowns. If I click Reset Button, It has to rest the values. Ist time  values get reset, but next time onwards dropdown is not working and facing above error : Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true'.
2) 1st and 2nd dropdowns are Mandatory but for 3rd dropdown, I need to write a logic for it and the logic is for 2nd dropdown if the value is "yes" then 3rd dropdown should mark as mandatory otherwise not needed.

**TS File**

```js
    export class AppComponent {
        PepPartner: "";
        PepBlacklisted: "";
        Blacklist: "";
        public formGroup: FormGroup;
        constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

        screenofAML() {
            let self = this;
            this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
                PepPartner: ['', Validators.required],
                PepBlacklisted: ['', Validators.required],
                Blacklist: ['', Validators.required],
            });
        }

        validateForm() {
            if (this.formGroup.invalid) {
                this.formGroup.get('PepPartner').markAsTouched();
                this.formGroup.get('PepBlacklisted').markAsTouched();
                this.formGroup.get('Blacklist').markAsTouched();
                return;
            }
            else {
                const dataObj = {
                    PepPartner: this.formGroup.get('PepPartner').value,
                    PepBlacklisted: this.formGroup.get('PepBlacklisted').value,
                    Blacklist: this.formGroup.get('Blacklist').value,
                }
            }
        }
        onResetClick() {
            this.PepPartner = "";
            this.PepBlacklisted = "";
            this.Blacklist = "";
        }
    }
```

**HTML File**

```html
    <div class="space">
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Is this partner a PEP?</mat-label>
            <mat-error *ngIf="formGroup.get('PepPartner').hasError('required')">
                PEP Partner is required
            </mat-error>
            <mat-select disableRipple [(ngModel)]="PepPartner" formControlName="PepPartner">
                <mat-option></mat-option>
                <mat-option value="1">Yes</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="2">No</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Does this partner blacklisted</mat-label>
            <mat-error *ngIf="formGroup.get('PepBlacklisted').hasError('required')">
                Partner blacklisted is required
            </mat-error>
            <mat-select disableRipple [(ngModel)]="PepBlacklisted" formControlName="PepBlacklisted">
                <mat-option></mat-option>
                <mat-option value="1">Yes</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="2">No</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-error *ngIf="formGroup.get('Blacklist').hasError('required')">
                Blacklisted is required
            </mat-error>
            <input matInput placeholder="Blacklist(s)" [(ngModel)]="Blacklist" formControlName="Blacklist">
        </mat-form-field>
        <div class="button-position">
            <div class="text-right pr-0 pb-2">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <button type="button" id="button1" mat-raised-button class="text-uppercase app-btn app-btn-primary-border app-color-primary" (click)="validateForm()">Save</button>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <button type="button" id="button2" mat-raised-button class="text-uppercase app-btn app-btn-primary-border app-color-primary" (click)="onResetClick()">Clear</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: @Lahiru Mirihagonda ... Do you have any solution for that
?

Comment: @sandeep can you provide a stackblitz example

Comment: You are using `formControlName` together with `ngModel`. That will probably be your problem. Since you are using a reactive form, remove `ngModel`.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1qslbr This is a demo that fulfills your requirements. See if it helps. And @Silvermind is right. use either `reactive form` or `model driven form`. Not both at the same time.

Comment: @Slivermind...If I remove ngModel means for the first time also  Reset is not Working..